# Run my Selenium Scripts to test the Web page which is connected via Remote Desktop Connection?

Tags: windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to test the Web Pages which is connected through RDC and that web pages can't access from my machine browser, it can be accessed only through RDC. 
I wrote my scripts to open the chrome browser on my local machine,

> System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\selenium-java-
>          3.1.0\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe");
>   driver = new ChromeDriver();

**How can i write the selenium scripts to connect the browser which is from RDC.**

Please someone help me to do this.

This is what it showing me in commandLine

> > 18:29:15.105 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{marionette=true, browserName=firefox, version=, platform=WINDOWS}]])
> >     18:29:15.111 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities
> >     [{marionette=true, browserName=firefox, version=, platform=WINDOWS}]
> >     18:29:15.119 WARN - Exception thrown
> >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> >     org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
> >     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Build info: version:
> >     '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info: host:
> >     'DESKTOP-U53JQ9J', ip: '10.2.50.41', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch:
> >     'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111' Driver info:
> >     driver.version: unknown
> >             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
> >             at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
> >             at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.(DefaultSession.java:119)
> >             at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
> >
> > Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Build info: version:
> >     '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info: host:
> >     'DESKTOP-U53JQ9J', ip: '10.2.50.41', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch:
> >     'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111' Driver info:
> >     driver.version: unknown
> >             at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.callConstructor(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:89)
> >             at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.newInstance(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:63)
> >
> > ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> >             at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> >     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property;
> >     for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The
> >     latest version can be downloaded from
> >     https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
> >             at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:738)
> >
> > 18:29:15.374 WARN - Exception: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more
> >     information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest
> >     version can be downloaded from
> >     https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases 18:29:15.416 INFO -
> >     Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{marionette=true,
> >     browserName=firefox, version=, platform=WINDOWS}]]) 18:29:15.420 INFO
> >     - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{marionette=true, browserName=firefox, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] 18:29:15.430 WARN -
> >     Exception thrown java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> >     org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
> >     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Build info: version:
> >     '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info: host:
> >     'DESKTOP-U53JQ9J', ip: '10.2.50.41', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch:
> >     'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111' Driver info:
> >     driver.version: unknown
> >             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
> >     Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Build info: version:
> >     '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info: host:
> >     'DESKTOP-U53JQ9J', ip: '10.2.50.41', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch:
> >     'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111' Driver info:
> >     driver.version: unknown
> >             at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.callConstructor(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:89)
> >             at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.newInstance(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:63)
> >
> > 18:29:15.639 WARN - Exception: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more
> >     information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest
> >     version can be downloaded from
> >     https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases 18:29:15.676 WARN -
> >     Exception thrown java.lang.NullPointerException
> >             at java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(Unknown Source)
> >             at java.util.HashMap.putAll(Unknown Source)
> >
> > 18:29:15.749 WARN - Exception: null  java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> >     The path to the driver executable must be set by the
> >     webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see
> >     https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be
> >     downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

**This is my code in eclipse**

> public void setup() throws Throwable  {
>   //        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\selenium-java-3.1.0\geckodriver-v0.14.0-win64\geckodriver.exe");
>         File file = new
>   File("C:\selenium-java-3.1.0\geckodriver-v0.14.0-win64\geckodriver.exe");
>         System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
>   file.getAbsolutePath());
>                 DesiredCapabilities cap=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();          cap.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);      cap.setBrowserName("firefox");
>         URL url=new URL("http://192.168.2.98:4444/wd/hub");         WebDriver
>   driver=new RemoteWebDriver(url, cap);
>         driver.get("http://learn-automation.com/");

Comment: yes,after running **java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register** When i run this code in eclipse,**DesiredCapabilities cap=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
cap.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);URL url=new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");WebDriver driver=new RemoteWebDriver(url, cap);driver.get("http://learn-automation.com/");**  I got error in command line **Exception thrown java.util.concurrent. ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:** and in eclipse **Unable to create new remote session**

Comment: Do you have a hub running? do you have the browsers installed? do you have the drivers in you path?

Comment: Everything was set but still getting the same error in commandline and eclipse

Comment: Can you post the stacktraces, maybe I can help you.

Comment: hub is running and it shows in CommandLine like **18:29:15.672 INFO - Trying to create a new session on test slot {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=firefox, maxInstances=5, platform=WIN10}**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to execute the tests on a remote machine. you can make this possible via [Selenium Grid Server](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/grid/).

With Selenium Grid Server you can set up a node on you remote pc and let that node open a browser.
This node is connected to a hub, the hub will receive the commands and sent them to the node.

Is this what you are looking for?

An example configuration for a hub:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-<version>.jar -role hub -hubConfig hubConfig.json
```

Contents of hubConfig.json

```
{
    "_comment" : "Configuration for Hub - hubConfig.json",
    "host": ip,
    "maxSessions": 5,
    "port": 4444,
    "cleanupCycle": 5000,
    "timeout": 300000,
    "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
    "servlets": [],
    "prioritizer": null,
    "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
    "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
    "nodePolling": 180000,
    "platform": "WINDOWS"
}
```

An example configuration for a node:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-<version>.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodeConfig.json
```

Contents of nodeConfig.json

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "opera",
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
      "webdriver.opera.driver": "C:/Selenium/drivers/operadriver.exe",
      "binary":"C:/Program Files/Opera/44.0.2510.1159/opera.exe"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
      "webdriver.chrome.driver": "C:/Selenium/drivers/chromedriver.exe",
      "binary":"C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
      "webdriver.gecko.driver": "C:/Selenium/drivers/geckodriver.exe",
      "binary":"C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"
    }
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 5,
  "port": 5555,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://localhost:4444",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
}
```

### Drivers downloads

Place all the drivers in your path variable

- [Chrome driver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)
- [FireFox driver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)
- [Microsoft Edge driver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)
- [Opera driver](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases)

### Browsers  downloads

- [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html)
- [FireFox](https://www.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/new/)
- [Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/nl-nl/windows/microsoft-edge)
- [Opera](http://www.opera.com/nl)

Comment: Yes,this is what i'm looking for. But still I'm unclear. i have gone through [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2). And when i run this code '  WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
' its shows me an error **SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new session**,

Comment: Did you start a java hub and node via `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-<version>.jar -role hub -hubConfig hubConfig.json` 

and

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-<version>.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodeConfig.json` 

for more information see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/selenium-grid/8702/selenium-grid-configuration#t=201705040847276869472

Answer (score 1):

Selenium cannot connect to the remote server through RDP.

You'll need to set up VPN connection between services or something like [**ngrok**](https://ngrok.com/)

Comment: You trying to resolve localhost there or what is the problem?

Comment: I have to test one website which is from Remote Desktop connection of another computer, also i have connected VPN.  I dont know how to write selenium scripts to connect the browser of another computer through RDC.